# PHP complex preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace a string I have coded like this

```
jsbdahsbdaisd [[aaa]]ID1#random text 1[[/aaa]] asdasdasd [[aaa]]ID2#random text 2[[/aaa]]
```

to something like

```
jsbdahsbdaisd <span onclick="function(ID1)">random text 1</span> asdasdasd <span onclick="function(ID2)">random text 2</span>
```

Is it possible to do this with preg_replace in one line?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah possible, what have you tried ? We're not here to do your work. At least show some efforts.

Comment: What should happen if the string is like this: `[[aaa]]asd[[aaa]]blabla[[/aaa]][[/aaa]]`?

Comment: [Sure - just replace `/\[\[aaa\]\]([^#]+)([^\[]+)\[\[\/aaa\]\]/` with `<span onclick="function(\1)">\2</span>`](http://regex101.com/r/gM9pU3)

Comment: @ohaal, then he should delve into writing his own parser. :D

Comment: @tenub Meh, using recursive regex it would be possible :)

Comment: @ohaal: since the OP want to make clickable tags, you can be sure that there is no nested bbcode-like tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this as a find/replace:

```
<?php

$string = 'jsbdahsbdaisd [[aaa]]ID1#random text 1[[/aaa]] asdasdasd [[aaa]]ID2#random text 2[[/aaa]]';

$new_string = preg_replace('/\[\[aaa\]\](ID[0-9]+)#([-A-Z0-9 _.]+)\[\[\/aaa\]\]/i', '<span onclick="function($1)">$2</span>', $string);

print $new_string;
```

This outputs:

```
jsbdahsbdaisd <span onclick="function(ID1)">random text 1</span> asdasdasd <span onclick="function(ID2)">random text 2</span>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I was going crazy trying to get this solved.